# How to create "guitar string vibration" animation JS

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

I want to create some very special animation on my website.

I need to create a string, which will vibrate like a guitar string when user move mouse trough it.

So this dom element have to be bended in the place of cursor attachment and act like a vibrating guitar string on cursor leave.

I was trying to find solution on greensock.com and it seems like there is no solution there.

Please help me)

Comment: Check this pen out: https://codepen.io/wentin/pen/VYegqq . Edit: Not my work.

Comment: @Coss this thing is not bending in the place of the cursor attachment. it bends in center every time

Comment: A problem with guitar string vibration is  it is more complex than the example `Coss` provided. If you pull a string at a center, it vibrates like in example (with small ripples on the sides), but if you pull it on the side the vibration slowly transfers towards the center. I guess what I'm trying to say is you should decide on what kind of vibration pattern you want, when you do - you should be able to adjust the example `Coss` linked to your needs.

Comment: @Zero i think, that vibration pattern about what i am asking about is much more complicated and i am not able even to do math of this animation pattern. And even after doing math i will need to convert it into code and i am not sure what approach do i have to use, so what i am trying to find is 100% ready for use solution.